# how to make background layout transparent when pop up slides

Tags: android

My code is as shown below:

activity_product_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/productLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_base" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorMercuryE1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:contentPaddingBottom="20dp">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white">

                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="219dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/white">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_product_food" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/ic_like"
                                android:layout_width="38dp"
                                android:layout_height="38dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_like" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/itemPrice"
                                android:layout_width="65dp"
                                android:layout_height="34dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                                android:background="@drawable/background_product_price"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="$ 7.33"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                android:textSize="13sp" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:paddingLeft="12dp">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="17dp"
                                    android:layout_height="17dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/ic_like_review" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/likedReview"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                                    android:text="224"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorGray89"
                                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/itemName"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                                android:text="Fried Pepper Mint Fish"
                                android:textColor="@color/colorFuscousGray"
                                android:textSize="15sp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="14dp"
                                android:layout_height="17dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_spice" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="14dp"
                                android:layout_height="17dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/icon_leaf" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="14dp"
                                android:layout_height="17dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/icon_fish" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/foodTruckName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="Chicken gourmet"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorGray89"
                            android:textSize="13sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/itemInfo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                            android:paddingRight="12dp"
                            android:text="@string/dummy_text"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorFuscousGray"
                            android:textSize="13sp" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/reviewLine"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorMercuryE1"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/reviewText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                            android:text="Reviews"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorFuscousGray"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />

                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                            android:clipToPadding="false"
                            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/progressLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_review"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/floating_button_message" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/reviewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/remarkText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="147dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="Write your review"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGray8c"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray8c"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/doneButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorRoyalPurple"
            android:text="Done"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ProductInfoActivity.java

```
public class ProductInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private Animation slide_down, slide_up;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 //Load animation
        slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.slide_down);

        slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.slide_up);

reviewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reviewLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                reviewLayout.startAnimation(slide_up);
            }
        });

.....


}
```

Now, basically what happens here is when the pop up slides up, the background does not become translucent/transperant. [I want to make it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UguPt.png). So what modification should I do?

Comment: try using bottomsheet

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=0775WL2yFs3y8AewiKyACA&gws_rd=ssl#q=bottomsheet+android+github

Comment: @DivyeshPatel it worked

Answer (score 1):

you add parent layout that require full height for reviewLayout , and control the layout background color after animation finished

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

http://mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/

and use this android:popupBackground 
set color like this     2c000000

and look the example I've send you,,, you have done a lot of mistakes

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

replace your `view` with `dialog`...